# Unexpected error when combining beamer + tabular + newif

Tags: beamer

The code is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Ok}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\newif\ifok
\oktrue

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
    \ifok
    Hello
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        ok \\
    \end{tabular}
    \fi 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This small code piece makes pdflatex to outout (only last lines):

```
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 19.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> ok.tex

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> ok.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Any idea to fix this or should I throw out the use of \newif?

Answer (score 5):

Beamer does lots of "interesting" re-arrangements of its inputs, you can use the `[fragile]` option on a frame so it uses a safer, slower, mechanism:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Ok}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\newif\ifok
\oktrue

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \ifok
    Hello
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        ok \\
    \end{tabular}
    \fi

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank your very much. Maybe, a rule of thumb could be: if doesn't work as expected, use "fragile".

Comment: @CasséHugues that's the rule I used here:-)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\begin{frame}
    \ifok
    Hello
    {\begin{tabular}{c}
        ok \\
    \end{tabular}}
    \fi 
\end{frame}
```